# How do you add together an attribute of all instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning OOP, and I wanted to make a program to keep track of my savings, I am trying to add together how much I have saved over each month.

Each month will be an object, I want to add together (month.budget + month.to_save_each_month) of each month

```py
class Saving():
    to_save_each_month = 961.71
    spent = []
    # saved = this is where i would like to add them up
    def __init__(self,wage,rent):
        self.wage = wage
        self.rent = rent
        self.budget = round(self.wage - (self.to_save_each_month + self.rent),2)
    def spending(self, spend):
        self.budget = round(self.budget - spend, 2)
        self.spent.append(spend)
```

Comment: _but i cant seem to get it working_ - please be more specific. Do you get errors or incorrect output? Show us all relevant information.

Comment: Sorry i meant i just cant figure out how to get it working, ive been researching for the last hour but cant seem to find any way to add together an attribute of all objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're gonna have to keep track of all created instances of your class, since there's no built-in way to do this. The simplest way to do this is just to add an empty list as a class variable and append each instance to it in the init method:

```
class Saving:
    # your other class variables here
    instances = []

    def __init__(self,wage,rent): 
        # your init logic here
        self.__class__.instances.append(self)
```

Now you just need to create a method to return the sum you want:

```
def savings_sum(self):
    return sum(month.budget + month.to_save_each_month for month in self.instances)
```

It may make more sense internally for this method to be a class method, since it only really need to access the class attribute `instances`, but that's beside the point - it should work either way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `Saving` objects in a list named for example `savings_list`, you can simply do this:

```
total_savings = sum(x.budget + x.to_save_each_month for x in savings_list)
```